# Update issue in a DataGridView

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I can do things almost well with below SqlAdapter

```
Private SqlDA As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tblContacts", SqlConn)
```

But if I use below then I get thrown because of below usage after I retrieved data from SQL to modify and then update with DataTable. Btw, There is Primary Key on first field which is Identity means increase automatically you know. Below is not contain that field's title.(ContactID)

```
Private SqlDA As New SqlDataAdapter("Select FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber, Tarih from tblContacts", SqlConn)
```

Here is whole the code:

```
    Dim TheDataTable As New DataTable
Private SqlConn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=PC-N39\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ADO_PRACTICE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sas")
Private SqlDA As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tblContacts", SqlConn)
Private SqlDataSet As New DataSet
Private SqlCmdBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(SqlDA)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    SqlDA.Fill(TheDataTable)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = TheDataTable
    InitializeDataGridView()
End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim x As Integer
    x = SqlDA.Update(TheDataTable)
    MessageBox.Show(CStr(x) & " record(s) updated")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second statement doesn't contains the PrimaryKey of the table or a unique index column.
That's the reason why SqlCommandBuilder fails to generate the appropriate UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT commands looking at the SelectCommand stored in the DataAdapter.

I can't see any solution than readding the ContactID to your query

[See MSDN docs on SqlCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't want to show contactID field in DataGridView column and the other thing that What should I do if I don't want to show one or more fields columns title in any DataGridView with this case? Things are ok with Select * from tblContacts.

Comment: I think you should explore the options provided by the DataGridView to hide columns. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c24a0d7.aspx

Comment: Your suggestion is well enough to handle that case. Thanks for that @Steve, But I have another issue that occurs like this "Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records." This causes because I tried to modify a cell data on latest row which just added by btnUpdate to the DataGridView and then thrown.